# Generics and the Entity framework

Tags: c#, vb.net, entity-framework, generics, entities

In my database there are 5 fields at the end of each table:

- State
- CreatedDate
- CreatedBy
- ModifiedDate
- ModifiedBy

I am using the entity framework to generate the POCO objects for the database.
I have Dal layer to handle all of the CRUD operations.

It's a pain to constantly copy and paste the same code to fill in the 5 fields.
I am wondering if anyone has a generic method that can handle any entity object and fill the fields in for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should implement a common base class that has these properties, and derive your POCO classes from that base class.

You can automatically handle setting things like the Create/ModifiedDate and User by overriding SaveChanges() in your context class.  That frees the object consumers from the need to set those properties everywhere the classes are consumed.

Here's an example of that sort of code from one of my projects (in my case, objects that have a LastModified property implement an interface IHasLastModified):

```
    public override int SaveChanges()
    {
        DateTime now = DateTime.UtcNow;
        foreach (ObjectStateEntry entry in (this as IObjectContextAdapter).ObjectContext.ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntries(EntityState.Added | EntityState.Modified))
        {
            if (!entry.IsRelationship)
            {
                IHasLastModified lastModified = entry.Entity as IHasLastModified;
                if (lastModified != null)
                    lastModified.LastModified = now;
            }
        }

        int changes = base.SaveChanges();
        return changes;
    }
```

Comment: This is fantastic and a great idea. There is the small issue of getting automatically created POCO objects to inherit from the base class. Although I could modify the .tt file to add this inheritance, can you share how you would do this?

Comment: I don't actually auto-generate my POCO's.  Generally you can modify the .tt template files.   Which generator are you using?

Comment: There are the DbContext generator, Model First Generator, Database First Generator and possibly others all within Entity Framework.

Comment: Right, so all of these work similarly using the .tt files. I was easily able to make them work with the base class by modifying the .tt file. I was hoping there was an alternate method without modifying the .tt file.

Comment: And there sure is! I didn't realize that the entity framework generates partial classes. Implementing new or overriding functionality is trivial in the entity framework. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I ran into a similar problem, and have detailed my approach at http://lourenco.co.za/blog/2013/07/audit-trails-concurrency-and-soft-deletion-with-entity-framework/